# How to remove whitespace at specfic position/index of Python string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to remove whitespace at a specific position within a Python string.

For example, I have the following string: `time = "Year 1.2 Quarter 4"`

Since I want Quarter to be abbreviated, I replaced the word using this:

```
time = time.replace('Quarter','Q')  ##Output: "Year 1.2 Q 4"
```

However, I would like the result to be this: `Year 1.2 Q4`.
How can I remove the whitespace between `Q` and `4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `time` as variable name as it might conflict with `time` package.

You can use `replace()` as following:

```
time_str = "Year 1.2 Quarter 4"
time_str = time_str.replace("uarter ", "")

print(time_str)
```

output:

```
Year 1.2 Q4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
time = "Year 1.2 Quarter 4"
new_time = re.sub('uarter\s(?=\d)', '', time)
```

Output:

```
'Year 1.2 Q4'
```